# How to find all groups in ActiveDirectory where the current user has WriteProperty access?

Tags: c#, linq, active-directory

Currently i'd like to find all groups within the Active Directory where the current user has the right [WriteProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectoryrights.aspx).

The problem is that i can find all groups where the user directly is inserted, but when the user is within a group and that group has write access it won't show up. I thought that setting the booleans of [GetAccessRules()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directoryobjectsecurity.getaccessrules.aspx) would help here, but it doesn't.

So here is the code i already have:

```
var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
var allDomains = Forest.GetCurrentForest().Domains.Cast<Domain>();

var allSearcher = allDomains.Select(domain =>
    {
        var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain.Name));
        //Apply some filter to focus on only some specfic objects
        searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group)(name=*part_of_group_name*))";
        return searcher;
    });

var itemsFound = allSearcher
    .SelectMany(searcher => searcher.FindAll()
        .Cast<SearchResult>()
        .Select(result => result.GetDirectoryEntry()));

var itemsWithWriteAccess = itemsFound
    .Where(entry => entry.ObjectSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(SecurityIdentifier))
        .Cast<ActiveDirectoryAccessRule>()
        .Where(rule => rule.IdentityReference == identity)
        .Where(rule => (rule.ActiveDirectoryRights & ActiveDirectoryRights.WriteProperty) == ActiveDirectoryRights.WriteProperty)
        .Count() > 0);

foreach (var item in itemsWithWriteAccess)
{
    Debug.Print(item.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time and the help of [Harvey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/452199/harvey-kwok) through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931982/how-can-i-check-if-a-user-has-write-rights-in-active-directory-using-c/4941688#4941688) i finally found a good working solution.

As already explained by Harvey it can be a little difficult to really further understand what you'll get back in `entry.Properties["allowedAttributesEffective"].Value`. But for normal purposes all you have to check for a write permission is that this field is simply *not null*.

Here is the sample code:

```
// (replace "part_of_group_name" with some partial group name existing in your AD)
var groupNameContains = "part_of_group_name";

var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
var allDomains = Forest.GetCurrentForest().Domains.Cast<Domain>();

var allSearcher = allDomains.Select(domain =>
{
    var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain.Name));

    // Apply some filter to focus on only some specfic objects
    searcher.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectClass=group)(name=*{0}*))", groupNameContains);
    return searcher;
});

var directoryEntriesFound = allSearcher
    .SelectMany(searcher => searcher.FindAll()
        .Cast<SearchResult>()
        .Select(result => result.GetDirectoryEntry()));

var allowedTo = directoryEntriesFound.Select(entry =>
    {
        using (entry)
        {
            entry.RefreshCache(new string[] { "allowedAttributesEffective" });
            var rights = entry.Properties["allowedAttributesEffective"].Value == null ? "read only" : "write";
            return new { Name = entry.Name, AllowedTo = rights };
        }
    });

foreach (var item in allowedTo)
{
    var message = String.Format("Name = {0}, AllowedTo = {1}", item.Name, item.AllowedTo);
    Debug.Print(message);
}
```