# Looking for a way (preferably an API) to determine Effective Permissions on Active Directory object

Tags: winapi, active-directory, access-control, windows-security

We have a custom Active Directory integrated web app that helps users perform some self-service on their accounts (e.g. update photo, change phone number, reset password etc.) Our app runs on domain-joined servers, as Local System, and is thus able to authenticate to the AD using the server account(s).

We use a service connection point, that the app's clients use to locate an instance of our app. (Our app clients are hard-coded to look for certain keywords which are published on the servie connection point's *keywords* attribute.)

We recently had a situation wherein someone (we believe accidentally) changed the keywords on one of the service connection points resulting in an outage, since the clients could no longer find our SCP when querying the AD for our keyword(s).

The customer is a bit upset about this and wishes for us to provide them the ability to determine who can change the keywords on our SCPs. This feedback was passed on from our sales guys to us, and now we need to provide some way of helping them figure out who can change the keywords on our SCPs.

So, we're looking for an API to help us to determine Effective Permissions on our Active Directory service connection point objects, so we can alleviate this situation for the customer. We couldn't quite find an Effective Permissions / Access API that could help us list all the users who have effective write access to the keyword and other attributes on our SCPs.

**Is there an API/other way that one can use to determine Effective Permissions on an Active Directory object?**

It needs to be able to list all the users who have a specified access on a specified set of attributes of an Active Directory object.

Answer (score 0):

This [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931982/how-can-i-check-if-a-user-has-write-rights-in-active-directory-using-c) may be able to help you.  [LINQ to LDAP](http://linqtoldap.codeplex.com/discussions/370594) should also allow you to access the information pretty easily as well.