# c# DirectoryEntrie Propertie allowedAttributesEffective is always null

Tags: c#, permissions, active-directory, ldap

I have a very old project that worked like a charm for many years.
All of a sudden It seems that the following code snippet is only returning false because the *"allowedAttributesEffective"* property is null, and therefore thinking that the user has no rights to Modify an AD object

```
public static bool checkWritePermission(DirectoryEntry de) {
  de.RefreshCache(new string[] { "allowedAttributesEffective" });
  log.write("Write permission == " + (bool)(de.Properties["allowedAttributesEffective"].Value != null), 5);  
  // Outputs always -> "Write permission == False"  
  return de.Properties["allowedAttributesEffective"].Value != null;
}
```

The "original" codes taken years ago from here: [How can I check if a user has write rights in Active Directory using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931982/how-can-i-check-if-a-user-has-write-rights-in-active-directory-using-c)

In reality the user that executes this code should have modify permissions on all AD Objects (proven by the fact that I can Modify all objects in question via Active Directory Users and Computers Management Interface)

Any Ideas what the issue could be here?
I have also tried with ldapsearch on linux to see if I can read the property *"allowedAttributesEffective"* but I have not found a clear answer if that should even be the case as it is not returning anything on any LDAP object

Comment: The issue is probably out of that function, maybe a filter no longer matching the entry from AD, how do you get the given directory entry ?

Comment: @EricLavault The Directory entrie is valid. I can read every property I have searched for. Its just that single Propertie that's not working anymore, that previously perfectly reflected the users permission on that given object.