# Checking write access on AD attributes (allowedAttributesEffective is empty)

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

A follow-up to [How can I check if a user has write rights in Active Directory using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931982/how-can-i-check-if-a-user-has-write-rights-in-active-directory-using-c)

I ran this to grant the user write access to an attribute:

`dsacls "OU=Users,OU=OrgABC,DC=foo,DC=local" /G "FOO\example.user:WP;title;user" /I:S`

The goal is to allow a user to have write access to an attribute for all users in an OU. Through ADUC, I can indeed write to that attribute. The *Effective Access* tab shows the user can read both `allowedAttributes` and `allowedAttributesEffective`.

Just like the referenced question, I call `RefreshCache` then `de.Properties["allowedAttributesEffective"]`. As a domain admin, it returns attributes. As a domain user, it is empty. I believe constructed attributes are not replicated, but I don't think that should matter here. Just to be safe, I manually pointed to the same DC for all my tests (and everything remained the same).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It shows up if using `DirectorySearcher`:

```
...
de.PropertiesToLoad.Add("allowedAttributesEffective")
searcher.FindAll()
...
```

Of course, I have to run a search, but this seems to fit what I'm doing. This may not be an answer for some, I'd still love to know why `RefreshCache` doesn't work.