# How to list all users in Active Directory in DropDownList Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, active-directory

I am using Visual Studio 2005 C#.

I am trying to retrieve the list of users in my Active Directory and insert them into a *DropDownList* control.

May I know how do I pull out the users and how can I insert them into the *DropDownList* 
control?

---

**EDIT:**

There are many parts of the functionality I would wish to complete.

Firstly is to list all users in a *DropDownList*, and having 2 checkboxes, *User* and *Admin*, and base on the role assigned to the user in the *DDL*, appropriate checkboxes will be checked.

Checking and unchecking of the role checkboxes will also assign/revoke the roles accordingly.

Comment: What are the criteria ? Have you started off with something and stuck, please expand the post on the same. To start of this reading might help [`Almost everything in AD`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for all users
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

This code could be rather slow - especially if you have a large AD, and a large number of users in your AD. But then again: is it really helpful to list thousands of users in a single drop down?? You might need to rethink your strategy there....

**Update:** if you cannot use .NET 3.5, you'll have to use the "legacy" `DirectorySearcher` class instead - something like this:

```
// find your default naming context
DirectoryEntry deRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");
string defaultCtx = deRoot.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value.ToString();

// define a directory searcher for your default context
string searchRootLDAPPath = "LDAP://" + defaultCtx;
DirectoryEntry defaultDE = new DirectoryEntry(searchRootLDAPPath);

// define searcher - search through entire subtree, search for users 
// (objectCategory=Person)           
DirectorySearcher dsAllUsers = new DirectorySearcher(defaultDE);
dsAllUsers.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
dsAllUsers.Filter = "(objectCategory=Person)";

// get the results
SearchResultCollection result = dsAllUsers.FindAll();

// count the user objects found
int count = result.Count;
```

As I mentioned - this will *not* perform very well on a large AD, and you might run into limits (like max. of 1'000 users returned) and other issues. You should maybe allow users to **search** for users, e.g. by their name or something - rather than listing out **all** your users (depending on the size of your AD).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However I am using .NET 2.0, will it still work? What are other possible solutions instead of listing them by a DDL?

Comment: @RUiHAO: no, this will only work on .NET 3.5 and up, sorry. The other option would be to allow **searching** for users (instead of grabbing all of the thousands of users and displaying them....)

Answer (score 1):

Like marc_s answer, also my answer depends on .Net 3.5. But only due to the fact that it uses LINQ, which can be translated back into some foreach-loops, make the code also runnable under .Net 2.0.

But due to the fact that i'm a fan of DRY here is simply [the link to an old answer of myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4967387/57488).

Answer (score 0):

For current Domain ,

```
DirectorySearcher AllUsers = new DirectorySearcher(Domain.GetCurrentDomain().GetDirectoryEntry());
AllUsers.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
AllUsers.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
int count = AllUsers.FindAll().Count;
```