# How to add DropDownlist of all users to ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ListView control, I want to edit the InsertItem Template to include a Dropdownlist Item which contains a list of users in Membership Directory.

I tried this:

```
    MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.GetAllUsers();

    assigned_volunteerDropDownBox.DataSource = users;
    assigned_volunteerDropDownBox.DataBind();
```

The biggsest issue is that it says `assigned_volunteerDropDownBox` does not exist in the current context... In fact none of the TextBox items on the insert template are in the current context (is this normal)?

How would I go about doing this?  I want to be able to only allow the row to be updated with valid usernames.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906367/how-to-list-all-users-in-active-directory-in-dropdownlist-control), but it doesn't actually contain the code to DataBind to the DropDownList item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the `assigned_volunteerDropDownBox` from code behind; but it's probably easier to do the binding from the drop down control itself.  Create a property to bind to:

```
// lazy-loaded property
public MembershipUserCollection UsersCollection
{
    get
    { 
        if (_usersCollection == null)
        {
            _usersCollection = Membership.GetAllUsers();
        }
        return _usersCollection;
    }
}
MembershipUserCollection _usersCollection;
```

Then use `DataSource` on the `DropDownList`:

```
<asp:DropDownList RunAt="Server" DataSource=<%# UsersCollection %> ID="assigned_volunteerDropDownBox" />
```

Comment: Works beautifully!  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) to find controls in a template.

Comment: Good to know!  Still learning here.  I appreciate the tips and patience.