# How to check OU accessability in C # , DirectoryEntry?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryentry

I'm using DirectoryEntry class

Trying to read all  users from specific OU and sub OU's.

Following code is part of task

```
using(DirectoryEntry dEntry = new DirectoryEntry(dn))
using(DirectorySearcher dSearcher = new  DirectorySearcher(dEntry))
{
     dSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
     dSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user) (objectCategory=person))";
     foreach(SearchResult in dSearcher.FindAll())
     {
        //Do something...
     }
}
```

some of sub OU's are protected from reading for current user.
And i got task exception "one or more error accured"
I'm looking for way to check if OU is not accessible and skip it. And to write that OU to log.
I tried following :

```
 public void GetOu(List<MyUser> list, string path)
 {
     using (DirectoryEntry dEntry = new     DirectoryEntry(path))
     using(DirectorySearcher dSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(dEntry))
     {
           dSearcher.SearcherScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
           dSearcher.Filter = "(objectClass=organizationalUnit)";
           foreach(SearchResult result in dSearcher.FindAll())
           {
               GetUsersFromOU(list,result.GetDirectoryEntry());
            }
       }
 }
public void GetUsersFromOU(List<MyUser> list,DirectoryEntry ou)
{
     using (DirectorySearcher dSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(ou);
     dSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;
     dSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
     foreach (Search result in dSearcher.FindAll())
      {
          //Do something.... update list...
      }
 }
```

Now get no exceptions and skips not accessible OUs.
1.But still can't find what are the "bad ou"s 
2.run time is catastrophic...

Comment: What do you mean by not accessible? Do you mean does not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make sure that the user running the process has the appropriate permissions to perform the lookup.  This will be your Windows account in a desktop application and the account running the application pool in an ASP.NET application.

Comment: That's the point, i cannot be sure that user running app has permission for specific OU. So i need to collect "deny access"es. I need way to know if OU is accessable or not by user. User is defined by IIS.

Comment: Surely you should be using an Admin account if you are using AD (through C#)?

Comment: This question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810613/how-to-find-all-groups-in-activedirectory-where-the-current-user-has-writepropert

Comment: Surely you should be using an Admin account if you are using AD (through C#)?                                        That is great wish, but not my reality.

Comment: Thank you, that link is very helpfull!

Comment: @Yuri, no problem.  Don't forget to upvote/accept if the answer helped.